# Why GAN's (Generative Adverserial networks) are called "implicit" generative networks?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, computer-science, generative-adversarial-network

Adverserial Networks, such as GAN's, are called **"implicit"** networks. What does it mean? And, how do they differ from **"explicit"** generative networks? And what are **"explicit"** generative networks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me provide you a simple answer by starting a conversation between human and computer algorithms:

**The human says**: I have some data, I want to be able to generate more data that look like these. To be precise, I need to be able to generate more data from the *main distribution* that my training data is coming from.

**A Generative model says**: give me your data, I'll find a way to help you. Eighter I give you back the distribution that your data comes from, or I will provide you another clever way so you can generate more samples similar to your original data without even bothering with the distributions.

- **Explicit models are like**: give us training data, we give you the distribution of your data, so you can do whatever you want with it.

  - If you at least know the type of the distribution, that would be a huge help, my work is easier, I only need to find the parameters of the distribution ( for example, if you tell me that the distribution is Gaussian, so as my "learning process" is to estimate the Mean and Variance for you. It doesn't need to be Gaussian, I can work with more complex and high dimensional distributions too)
  - If you don't know the type of the distribution, but still want me to give you a distribution, explicitly, I can go with non-parametric models such as *Kernel Density Estimation*.
- **Implicit method say**: we give you the capability of generating new samples similar to your training data in crazy ways! For example, look at GANs, by playing a game on your data, in the end, we give you something, a black box, we call it a Generator, you can pass a random number to it and it will magically give you back a new sample. In training this black box, we won't bother with any distribution stuff directly.

Comment: Loved your explantion: simple yet pellucid.

Comment: I have some questions
1. For explicit generative models, what the instances where we already know the distribution, ? It seems kind of wierd to me. And, what type of models are used in the literature? 
2. For the implicit generative models, that is GAN's, what you are implying is that we can't model the distribution?
3. VAE's are implicit or explicit?

Thanks you in advance!!

Comment: Actually, a lot of data in the real world follows the famous Gaussian distribution (single variable or multivariate) such as the height of people in a certain country and many other natural data!  Poisson and Binomial also arise in many real-world problems. 
But! Data such as images and sounds are very high-dimensional and probably don't follow any of the know distributions, so working with them is a bit tricky.
As far as I recall, VAE's are explicit since in the design of the algorithm they try to learn a distribution with the help of a latent variable with a Gaussian prior.

Comment: This post seems to be useful: https://medium.com/@prakashpandey9/deep-generative-models-e0f149995b7c

Answer (score 0):

Okay, in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.03483.pdf), it says:

---

### "Prescribed probabilistic models are those that provide an explicit parametric specification of the distribution of an observed random variable **x** [...]. Most models in machine learning and statistics are of this form, whether they be state-of-the-art classifiers for object recognition, complex sequence models for machine translation, or fine-grained spatio-temporal models tracking the spread of disease. Alternatively, we can specify implicit probabilistic models that define a stochastic procedure that directly generates data."

Maybe to wrap it up: A *prescribed* probabilistic model wants to learn a set of parameters suitable for the task and data at hand, e.g. object classification. On the other hand, an *implicit* probabilistic model generates data, though to be fair, GANs are also fed with data, e.g. MNIST samples, and if properly tuned, they produce MNIST numbers themselves.

Hope that helps a bit!

PS: I'm not sure whether *explicit* generative networks exists at all. Are you sure, maybe you can send a reference? After all, one always wants to generate data with a GAN ...